# Copy selected features to another feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, features, select

I had two polyline feture classes representing the same objects that I spatially joined together to reconsile/consolidate data about.  At the time I was directed to remove some features from the joined feature class because they were not of interest at that point.  Subsiquently they now are and I want to bring them from one of the original layers into the joined layer.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not use the append tool?

Comment: Use compare tables and then select by attributes and finally append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only a few features and the attribute fields are the same in both layers, it might be simplest to start an edit session on both layers and just do a copy and paste.

If there are many features or uncommon attribute fields, the Append geoprocessing tool would be more suitable.

Comment: This is what I endded up doing. Thanks for the help.